# Not a recognized operator or type when #define new is added

Tags: c++, stl, new-operator, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to solve a part of my program, which has a #define new. Everything works well, until I try to create a class template that overrides the new operator, when I get the errors:

```
C:\Define_New_problem\main.cpp:18: error: expected type-specifier before 'dPushMemManFileLine'
C:\Define_New_problem\main.cpp:18: error: expected ';' before 'dPushMemManFileLine'
C:\Define_New_problem\main.cpp:21: error: expected ';' before '}' token
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

Using MinGW. The (simplified) code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

#define new dPushMemManFileLine( __FILE__, __LINE__ ) ? 0 : new

using namespace std;

static const int NUM_NEW_STACK_SIZE = 256;
static struct { const char* filename; unsigned int line; } g_NewStackMemDebug[NUM_NEW_STACK_SIZE];
static int g_CurStack = -1;

template <class T>
class mypair {
  private:
    int a, b;
  public:
    mypair (int first, int second)
      {a=first; b=second;}
    static void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
    }
};

int dPushMemManFileLine( const char* filename, unsigned int line )
{
    if(g_CurStack >= NUM_NEW_STACK_SIZE )
        return 0;

    g_CurStack++;
    g_NewStackMemDebug[g_CurStack].filename = filename;
    g_NewStackMemDebug[g_CurStack].line = line;

    return 0; // needed for the new passthrough trick

}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Has anyone a good idea on how do I solve this problem?

Comment: What's on line 18?  That is a good place to start.  Also `gcc -E` is your friend in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## **Don't.Ever.`#define`.Keywords.**

Please, just **don't**. It only makes problem. A `#define` replaces all occurences of the defined word with what you define it to be, so after the `#define`'d `new` gets expanded, the operator overload looks like the following:

```
static void* operator dPushMemManFileLine( __FILE__, __LINE__ ) ? 0 : new(size_t size)
    {
    }
```

Uuups....
Then of course the question remains, why did you do that?

Comment: The code is actually part of a larger program, and I'm trying to get two parts of the program to co-operate together (regarding the new operator), since one part of the program uses a class template that overrides operator new, and the rest of the program uses the overriden new...

Comment: If you're not senior enough to change the `#define`, you will have to `#undef` `new` before you can overload it. (Be aware, though, that this will prevent it from logging the file/line it was called at.)

Comment: This "technique" was heavily popularized by Microsoft, who use it in their MFC (I think) when `DEBUG` is defined in order to track memory leaks. @StrangeCode: Officially, `#defining` keywords invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: How about separating the class template to a .so or .dll library, would that be still compatible with the #define new macro?

Comment: "Don't Ever...." design a language where it is nigh impossible to find leaks without resorting to such mechanisms. The argument that this is "bad" is absurd. It's only bad if there is a alternate method. If you have no alternate, then telling us to "Don't Ever" doesn't really solve the problem now does it? I KNOW why it is a bad solution. Now show me a good solution that does what I want.

Answer (score 3):

I think when you expand the `new` in the line `static void* operator new(size_t size)`
 the error becomes pretty obvious:

```
class mypair {
    static void* operator dPushMemManFileLine( __FILE__, __LINE__ ) ? 0 : new(size_t size)
    { }
};
```

Using `#define` on keywords is a dangerous game :)

Answer (score 1):

As it's mentioned, the error is coming because your `#define new` is expanded at the `operator new` also.

To solve your problem, I can suggest you to try following; that will help you avoid using macros:

```
//overload new with LINE & FILE and call the function inside
void* operator new (size_t size, const char *FILE, const unsigned int LINE)
{
  dPushMemManFileLine(FILE, LINE);
  return malloc(size);
}

//overload the default new operator and throw something vague    
void* operator new (size_t size)
{ 
  class BadNewUsed {} bad;
  throw bad;  // throw it; since we can't catch it at compile time
}
```

Usage:

```
int *pi = new(__LINE__, __FILE__) int; // ok
double *pd = new double; // throws BadNewUsed out of your code,
```

Only effort you have to make is go and correct the call to `new` until it doesn't `throw`. That also you can do it fast with a simple technique. Just do

```
#define new abcd // to get compilation error wherever new is present
```

Now go and replace each call to `new` with `NEW`. Don't replace `operator new` implementation. Then do,

```
#define NEW new( __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

And compile the code. Note that this macro usage is for your debugging purpose and make things fast. I am not recommending it to use in production code.

You can achieve this using `templates` also if you don't want to use macros like `NEW`.

```
template<typename T>
T* NEW (const char* FILE, const unsigned int LINE)
{
  dPushMemManFileLine(FILE, LINE);
  return new T;  // can use default version or any overloaded version of 'new'
}
```

Usage:

```
int *p = NEW<int>(__FILE__, __LINE__);
```